# Wicket 1.5 - page serialization - how it works?

Tags: java, wicket

My application is filling up disk space with serialized pages. The are not being cleaned up at all - not even after session expiration. 
I order to find out the reason for it I need to understand how the serialization is working.

1) Does Wicket have hooks on HTTP Session which clan up page history when Session is terminated or times out?

2) What are the configuration options for page history?

3) Is is possible to configure page serialization to use HTTP Session and not temp dir?

4) Is is possible to configure page serialization to use in memory cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK.... so I've checked the code

1) yes

2) only folder path (`javax.servlet.context.tempdir`) can be configured over properties. `DiskDataStore` can be used to configure few additional things pragmatically: limit serialization size (default is 10 mb) and in memory page cache size.

3) yes - by registering `HttpSessionDataStore`

4) partly - it's possible to increment `StoreSettings#inmemoryCacheSize`, when it's full, wicket will start serialization to file - this makes sense.

Comment: Did you ever find out why the sessions were not being cleaned up, even after session expiration?

Comment: no, not yet, currently we have corn job that removes old folders.